# Custom Font not working in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts

I am trying to use a truetype (.ttf) font in my iOS app and it is not working. I have added the font to my project and added the target correctly. I added the font in the info.plist under fonts provided by application. I am using an NSAttributedString to display text and this is my code

```
UIFont *hrFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ocrb" size:18.0];
NSDictionary *hrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:hrFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *hrAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:hrString attributes: hrDict];

UIFont *barcodeFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"IDAutomation DataBar 34" size:22];
NSDictionary *barcodeDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:barcodeFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *barcodeAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString: alphaOnly attributes:barcodeDict];

[hrAttrString appendAttributedString:barcodeAttrString];
```

The barcode font displays correctly but the ocr font displays as the system font instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Add your custom font into your project , i.e. Dragged the font
>   file(**ocrb.TTF**) into XCode project.
>
> Edit Info.plist: Add a new entry with the key **"Fonts provided by
>   application"**.
>
> For each of your files, add the file name to this array

[image]

> Opened the font in font book(**double click on your font in finder**) to
>   see what the real filename is and I see this:

[image]

Now set font to your label

```
yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ocrb" size:15];
```

Comment: What I had to write in code to actually call the font was [UIFont fontWithName:@"OCRB" size:15]; for some unknown reason. But it ended up working out perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether that font is loaded or not by using the following code

```
NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];

for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
{
    NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
}
```

If your font is not loaded then download new font & add it into your project. After downloding & adding into project works for me.